# MongoDB: Sintaxis alternativa para db.devices.distinct()

Tags: mongodb

Tengo el siguiente trozo de código dentro de una consulta AF; funciona apropiadamente pero necesito darle formato según la norma de JSON:

```
"idDevice": {"$in": db.devices.distinct("_id", {"group.$id": 11})}
```

El problema de formato es con `db.devices.distinct()` en concreto, y parece que no hay forma de "jsonearlo", así que estoy intentando encontrarle una alternativa.

Buscando en la documentación oficial de Mongo he encontrado lo siguiente:

https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.0/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/

> The  [`db.collection.distinct()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.0/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/#db.collection.distinct)  method provides a wrapper around the  [`distinct`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.0/reference/command/distinct/#dbcmd.distinct)  command.

Así que he intentado lo siguiente, que sí es susceptible de ser formateado apropiadamente como JSON, pero al incorporarlo a mi consulta no obtengo resultados:

```
"idDevice": {"$in": ["distinct": "devices", "key": "_id", "query": {"group.$id": 11}]}
```

Se tira un buen rato procesando la consulta y finalmente me dice que no encuentra resultados.

¿Hay algún error en el código?

**EDICIÓN:**

Este trozo de código se encuentra dentro de un `$match`, etapa inicial de una consulta AF, entre los dos siguiente tipos de documentos:

Ejemplo de `sensorsDataHistoric`:

```
{
    "_id": {"$oid":"612c64e990977526b71d508b"},
    "idSensor": {"$numberLong": "3"},
    "idDevice": {"$numberLong": "1586"},
    ...
}
```

Ejemplo de `devices`:

```
{
    "_id": {"$numberLong": "1586"},
    "group": {"$id": {"$numberLong": "11"}},
    ...
}
```

La consulta en sí:

```
var pipeline = 
[
    {
        "$match": 
        {
            "idSensor": 3,
            "idDevice": {"$in": db.devices.distinct("_id", {"group.$id": 11})},
        }
    },
    {
        "$lookup":
        {
            "from": "devices",
            "localField": "idDevice",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as": "array"
        }
    },
    {
        "$unwind": "$array"
    },
    {
       "$project":
       {
           ...
       }
    }
]

db.sensorsDataHistoric.aggregate(pipeline)
```

El objetivo es filtrar los documentos de `sensorsDataHistoric` con `idSensor: 3` e `idDevice` asociado a `"group.$id": 11` (información que está en la colección `devices`; por otro lado, `idDevice` de `sensorsDataHistoric` equivale a `_id` de `devices`) antes de hacer el `$lookup` con la propia `devices`, de manera que no se incluyan en la unión documentos con `idDevice` relacionado con todos aquellos `"group.$id"` que no sean el 11.

**EDICIÓN 2:**

He intentando también incluir el filtro para los `idDevice` asociados a `"group.$id": 11` en el `$lookup`, pero debe de haber algún error de lógica y no obtengo resultados:

```
var pipeline = 
[
    {
        "$match": 
        {
            "idSensor": 3
        }
    },
    { 
        "$lookup": 
        {
            "from": "devices",
            "let": {"sensorsDeviceId": "$idDevice"},
            "pipeline": 
            [
                {
                    "$match": 
                    {
                        "$expr": 
                        {
                            "$and": 
                            [
                                {"$eq": ["$$sensorsDeviceId", "$_id"]}, 
                                {"$eq": ["group.$id", 11]}
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "as": "array"
        }
    },
    {
        "$unwind": "$array"
    },
    {
       "$project":
       {
           ...
       }
    }
]

db.sensorsDataHistoric.aggregate(pipeline)
```

Comment: Hace falta algo más de información, por ejemplo, ¿en qué etapa estás usando el operador `$in`? Y por otro lado, ¿porqué usar `distinct` sobre el campo `_id`? Todos los documentos de una colección de MongoDB tienen un campo `_id` distinto, por lo cual agrupar mediante este campo es absurdo. Tengo una idea de lo que pretendes hacer, pero no me queda clara la agrupación que haces (`distinct` es un filtro de agrupación). Saludos

Comment: Gracias, Mauricio. Ya he editado el mensaje original con la información necesaria.

Comment: Pero... hay algo que no entiendo... en `idSensor: {$numberLong: 3}`, ese $numberLong es una propiedad? (o es alguna forma de visualización que usas de los datos)... porque veo que comparas `idSensor: 3`... y no `idSensor.$numberLong: 3`
Lo pregunto porque he usado mongo en varios proyectos y nunca he visto eso de `$numberLong` ni de `$oid`... si me puedes aclarar ese punto. se me hace muy curiosa la forma en la que están almacenados los datos según tus ejemplos

Comment: Los pegué tal cual los copié de Compass. El `$numberLong` lo puedes omitir.

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema radica en el campo llamado `$id` dentro de `group`... porque `mongo` le da otro significado al `$` del lookup... así que la opción que veo es que apliques primero un filtro para extraer el valor de ese campo a otro que no inicie con `$` y con ese si hacer la comparación, te dejo aquí un ejemplo:

```js
var pipeline = 
[
   {
      "$match":{
         "idSensor":3
      }
   },
   {
      "$lookup":{
         "from":"devices",
         "let":{
            "sensorsDeviceId":"$idDevice"
         },
         "pipeline":[
            {
               "$addFields":{
                  "refId":{  //Este es el nuevo campo que vamos a añadir y tendrá el valor de $id
                     "$arrayElemAt":[ //Como filter nos devuelve un array, tomamos solo el primer elemento
                        {
                           "$filter":{ //Con esto filtramos solo la key que necesitamos que es $id
                              "input":{
                                 "$objectToArray":"$group"
                              },
                              "cond":{
                                 "$eq":[
                                    "$$this.k",
                                    {
                                       "$literal":"$id" //Solo tomamos el campo $id
                                    }
                                 ]
                              }
                           }
                        },
                        0
                     ]
                  }
               }
            },
            //Hasta este punto tendremos para cada device, una nueva propiedad refId: {k "$id", v: ElValorDe$id}
            {
               "$match":{
                  "$expr":{
                     "$and":[
                        {
                           "$eq":[
                              "$$sensorsDeviceId",
                              "$_id"
                           ]
                        },
                        {
                           "$eq":[
                              "$refId.v", //Aqui comparas contra ese valor
                              11
                           ]
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               }
            }
            //Ya si deseas, aqui puede remover el campo refId que agregamos previamente para que no quede dentro de la respuesta
         ],
         "as":"array"
      }
   }
]

db.sensorsDataHistoric.aggregate(pipeline)
```

Espero te sirva.
Saludos